# toggle function working as expected in jQuery 1.9.1+

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery to select a list of checkboxes. I am using the code as outlined in this fiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').toggle(function(){
        $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
        $(this).val('uncheck all')
    },function(){
        $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
        $(this).val('check all');        
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gubhaju/Vj6wY/3/

It was working in the fiddle, but not on my site (the button was disappearing). I then saw that the fiddle was using version 1.4.4, whereas my site was using version 2.1.1. After playing with the fiddle, I found that only with jQuery versions 1.8.3 and lower was the select working. What changed between 1.8.3 and 1.9.2? How can I modify this code so that it works for my version?

Comment: http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/ : *Note: This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.*

Comment: you can use jquery migrate plugin to run deprecated functions : http://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I showed you in my comment, there are quite a few changes in the versions of jQuery that you refer to. You can use the jQuery Migrate plugin (made by the jQuery team) to help troubleshoot the changes, but in a nutshell you can boil your code down to:

```js
$('.check').click(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', !$('input:checkbox').prop('checked'));
    $(this).val(($(this).val() == 'uncheck all') ? 'check all' : 'uncheck all')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" />Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" />Checkbox 2
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" />Checkbox 3
```

Comment: This will do the reverse of expected if you check/uncheck manually and then hit the button.

Comment: @smerny true. And if that's an issue for the OP, then a simple boolean will solve it http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2e9sadxq/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible work-around for you to use in newer versions (keeping your original code as intact as possible)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/3140/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.check:button').click(function(){
        if($(this).val() === 'check all') {
            $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            $(this).val('uncheck all')
        } else {
            $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', false);
            $(this).val('check all');        
        }
    })
})
```

Notice you'll also have to use `prop()` instead of `attr()` to set checked.

Answer (score 1):

One more possible workaround:

```js
$('.check:button').click(function () {
    var toggled = this.value == 'check all';
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', toggled);
    this.value = toggled ? 'uncheck all' : 'check all';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="check" value="check all" />
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" />Checkbox 1
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" />Checkbox 2
<input type="checkbox" class="cb-element" />Checkbox 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Your [toggle(Function, Function) no longer exists](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) from jQuery 1.9 upwards.

You can restore functionality by using a simple variable to track the state:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var state = 1;
    $('.check:button').click(function(){
        if (state) {
            $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
            $(this).val('uncheck all')
        } else {
            $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
            $(this).val('check all');
        }
        state = !state;
    });
});
```

Comment: `attr()` will not continue to work after flipping http://jsfiddle.net/Vj6wY/3142/